# Java HTML Web Scan

Tags: java, html, scanning

http://asprise.com/product/jia/html_javascript_scan_from_scanners.php

Need to use this and scan the document. Downloaded the program and run this code, it always says the error classNotfoundException: com.asprise.jia.ui.JiaApplet

[image]

I Placed the .java file in this structure

root folder

```
-Applet.html

-com

--asprise

---jia

----ui

-----JiaApplet.java
```

Please help me on this

Comment: Are you developing this, or just trying to use it?

Comment: I'm trying to use this

Comment: If you're trying to use this how are you able to place a directory on the webserver that's serving this page?